# Migrating Nginx reverse proxy to traefik => Services do not get served correctly

Tags: docker, nginx, traefik

I want to switch from Nginx as Reverse Proxy to traefik, since traefik offers sticky sessions, which I need in a Docker Swarm environment. This is part my Nginx Setup which worked fine:

```
   location / {
   proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;

   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
   proxy_read_timeout 600s;

   proxy_redirect    off;
   proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
   proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

 }


   location /auth/ {
   proxy_pass          https://127.0.0.1:8443;

   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
   proxy_read_timeout 600s;

   proxy_redirect    off;
   proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
   proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

 }
```

This is my traefik.toml:

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
    cipherSuites = [
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
    ]
    [entryPoints.keycloak]
    address = ":8443"  
    [entryPoints.shinyproxy]
    address = ":5000"  


[retry]

[docker]
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "langmarkus@hotmail.com"
storage = "acme/certs.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

And this is my compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  shinyproxy:
    build: /home/shinyproxy
    deploy:
      #replicas: 3
    user: root:root
    hostname: shinyproxy
    image: shinyproxy-example
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true" # Enable reverse-proxy for this service
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:analytics.data-mastery.com" # Domain name for the app
      - "traefik.port=443"
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true" # Enable reverse-proxy for this service
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:analytics.data-mastery.com" # Domain name for the app
      - "traefik.port=443"
    networks:
      - sp-example-net
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/certs/fullchain.pem
        target: /etc/x509/https/tls.crt
      - type: bind
        source: /home/certs/privkey.pem
        target: /etc/x509/https/tls.key
      - /home/theme/:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/custom/
    environment:
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=myadmin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=mypassword
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
  reverseproxy:
    image: traefik:v1.7.16
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml # Traefik configuration file
      - ./volumes/traefik-acme:/acme # Tell Traefik to save SSL certs here
    command: --api # Enables the web UI
    ports:
      - "80:80" # The HTTP port
      - "443:443" # The HTTPS port
      - "8080:8080" # The web UI

networks:
  sp-example-net:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

SSL is working, my keycloak service is running here: https://analytics.data-mastery.com:8443/auth/ . However, I want to archieve the same behaviour like with proxy_pass where I will not have to use ports in the URL. What do I have to change?

Comment: do you consider using traefik 2.1 ?

Comment: I would, I used 1.7.16 because I was not able to mount volumes to the newest image.

Answer (score 2):

in case you want to keep using the old traefik version, you can use the below stack files (you can also get rid of the traefik.toml and use only CLI commands)
With the below stack file, you will be able to access shinyproxy on `analytics.data-mastery.com` and keycloak on `analytics.data-mastery.com/auth` The import thing here is the defined `rule` https://docs.traefik.io/routing/routers/

you also don't need to expose the ports for this service, traefik will use the internal ones

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  shinyproxy:
    build: /home/shinyproxy
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
    user: root:root
    hostname: shinyproxy
    image: shinyproxy-example
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.backend.loadbalancer.swarm=true
      - traefik.backend=shinyproxy
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:analytics.data-mastery.com;
      - traefik.port=5000
      - traefik.docker.network=sp-example-net

  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.backend.loadbalancer.swarm=true
      - traefik.backend=keycloak
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:analytics.data-mastery.com;Path:/auth
      - traefik.port=8443
      - traefik.docker.network=sp-example-net
    networks:
      - sp-example-net
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/certs/fullchain.pem
        target: /etc/x509/https/tls.crt
      - type: bind
        source: /home/certs/privkey.pem
        target: /etc/x509/https/tls.key
      - /home/theme/:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/custom/
    environment:
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=myadmin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=mypassword

  reverseproxy:
    image: traefik:v1.7.16
    networks:
      - sp-example-net
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml # Traefik configuration file
      - ./volumes/traefik-acme:/acme # Tell Traefik to save SSL certs here
    command:
      - '--docker'
      - '--docker.swarmmode'
      - '--docker.domain=analytics.data-mastery.com'
      - '--docker.watch'
      - '--accessLog'
      - '--checkNewVersion=false'
      - '--api'
      - '--ping.entryPoint=http'
      # if you want to get reid of the toml file at all
      # - '--entrypoints=Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https'
      # - '--entrypoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS'
      # - '--defaultentrypoints=http,https'
      # - '--acme.entrypoint=https'
      # - '--acme.email=langmarkus@hotmail.com'
      # - '--acme.storage=/var/lib/traefik/acme.json'
      # - '--acme.acmelogging=true'
      # - '--acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=http'
      # - '--acme.domains=*.analytics.data-mastery.com,analytics.data-mastery.com'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"

networks:
  sp-example-net:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

if you want to jump directly to traefik2.1, here is a [link](https://github.com/wshihadeh/traefik_v2) that includes good examples for using it

Comment: I get a `"backend not found" "/"` error for both services with your file

Comment: try to access traefik dashboard (port :  8080) and check if the backends are created or not

Comment: you also need to add ```shinyproxy``` to the same network

Comment: `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` is what I get when I try to access 8080. Something might be off in general, look at this: `reverseproxy_1  | 216.244.66.247 - - [29/Feb/2020:15:54:26 +0000] "GET /xxx/step-mother-sex HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; DotBot/1.1; http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/dotbot, help@moz.com)" 24 "entrypoint redirect for http" "/xxx/step-mother-sex" 1ms`. What happens here? :-|

Comment: you are trying to access the 8080 with https, you need to do it with http